# Using Blog Parent Slug on Blog Posts Only

Tags: url-rewriting, slug

*(Advanced warning: novice question)*

I'm trying to find a way to add a blog slug to any blogs I post. Example:

mysite.com/theblog/aparticualrblogpost

mysite.com/theblog/anotherblogpost

Any page created that isn't a blog should use the standard structure:
mysite.com/agenericpage
mysite.com/parentpage/anothergenericchildpage

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Working : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WO_AwRKDt0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your custom permalink structure to:

```
/theblog/%postname%/
```

If you have any custom post types used on your site, you’ll need to make sure that they don’t get the /theblog/ prepended to their URLs.  To remove it, simply set with_front to false where the custom post types are registered:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
```

You also need to flush the WordPress rewrite rules after making this change – just go back to Settings > Permalinks save again the permalink.

You are done.